# What do curly brackets enclosing value literals evalue to in function call?

Tags: c++

I recently received [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34003267/607407) that uses the following syntax:

```
map.left.insert({165, "NODE_A"});
```

[It works.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ded9b63a5684680) But I have totally no idea what does this syntax mean.

It could be some kind of anonymous `struct` initialization, or maybe a way to avoid including some `struct`'s header file. But these are just ideas, I found nothing about it on google.

Comment: This _must_ be a duplicate, but I can't find a similar previous answer...

Comment: Because the keywords are problematic here. This is also why I was unable to google anything about it.

Comment: The right keyword here is [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), but even with that I can't find anything that can be a good/canonical duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 2):

It is a new feature added in c++11. It allows you to instantiated a object just passing its constructor arguments.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a, char b) {}
};

void func(Foo a)
{}

int main()
{
    func({2, 'c'});
}
```

Comment: Does this even work if `Foo` is not defined in that scope? Like when only `func(Foo);` is defined and `Foo` is "incomplete class"?

Comment: Also does it work with "pass by refference" syntax? Eg. `func(Foo&)`

Comment: @TomášZato, There's no way the compiler can tell whether the initializer is valid without the class definition. And since it creates a temporary, unnamed object, it won't work with a reference that requires a non-temporary object, but it will with, e.g., `const Foo&`.

Comment: and to pass by reference, you need the object to be created beforehand, except when you want a temporary (using a const object (`func(const Foo&)`), or by using a move semantic (`func(Foo&&)`)

Answer (score -1):

It is an initialiser list

Just like with a function that takes a vector of ints can be called with an initializer list of values, rather than making a vector and then pushing stuff into it and then handing it off to the function, i.e.

```
someFunc({2,3,4,5,6});
```

Looks like the same deal for your question in the previous answer. You can go even more crazy *if* the function that was being called accepted a vector of paired values using syntax like the following . .

```
someFunc({
       {165, "NODE_A"},
       {167, "NODE_B"},
       // etc . . .
    });
```

It is just a C++11 nicety.

Comment: I don't get it. What does it do? Does it require that `map` is defined in header?

Comment: Thanks for adding more info, I can understand much more now.